# Set of complex sequences is a closed linear subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A=\{\alpha=(a_1,a_2,...):a_n\in\mathbb{C},\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n\text{ exists }\}$ the set of convergent complex sequences and $B=\{\alpha=(a_n)\in A:\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=0\}$ the set of complex sequences converging to zero.

> How do I show that $B$ is a closed linear subspace of $A$?

I think I have to show that $A\backslash B$ is open by constructing an open ball around any sequence in $B$. But I wouldn't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly easier to show that a convergent sequence of elements from $B$ has its limit also in $B$; this is an equivalent definition of closed sets in a metric space. Remember that you are taking sequences of sequences here.

**Edit:** (Sketch of proof).
Let $(a_n^{(k)})_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $B=c_0$, and suppose that $(a_n^{(k)})\to (a_n)\in A$ as $k\to\infty$. (That is, the sequence $(a_n^{(k)})_{k=1}^\infty$ converges in $A$ to $(a_n)$. In particular $a_n^{(k)}\to a_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, and this convergence is *uniform* over all $n$.) Set $a=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ which exists because $(a_n)\in A$. The proof is complete by showing that $a=0$. Let $k,n\in\mathbb N$ and look at 
$$
|a|=|a-a_n+a_n-a_n^{(k)}+a_n^{(k)}|\leq |a-a_n|+|a_n^{(k)}-a_n|+|a_n^{(k)}|.
$$
It remains to show that the right hand side of the above can be made small for all sufficiently large $k,n$, which I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm not really sure what the limit of a sequence of sequences would look like. Could it be the zero sequence?

Comment: It could indeed be the zero sequence. The question is: what is the defining property of $B$, and what does that mean the limit of the sequence of sequences must satisfy?

Comment: The limit of the limit of the sequence of sequences should be zero

Comment: Could you help me a bit further please?

Comment: I have added a short sketch of the proof, with some details left for you to fill in.

Comment: Why exactly does the inequality hold?

Comment: This is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: This use of the triangle inequality is not totally clear to me, I'm afraid. Could you maybe post the steps inbetween?

Comment: If I take the limit of $k\rightarrow\infty$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$, doesn't the rhs go to 0?

Comment: This is to be shown, but yes.

Comment: How would I show it?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon>0$, find $N$ and $K$ large enough so that, for all $n\geq N$ and $k\geq K$, the RHS is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is that all I have to do to show that the RHS goes to zero?